# SQL - how to get max count for 2 tables sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to just display count(LEG.LEG#) that is the biggest value, how do i achieve it. i know i can use max but how to use max in this case.

Query,

```
select leg.T#,count(leg.LEG#) 
from trktripleg leg,trktrip trip 
WHERE leg.T#  = trip.T# AND trip.L#='10001' 
GROUP BY leg.T# 
ORDER by leg.T# ASC;
```

Result,

```
        T# COUNT(LEG.LEG#)
---------- ---------------
         1               3
         3               3
         8               3
        18               3
        21               3
        25               4
        26               3
        29               3
        35               4
        37               5
        39               3

        T# COUNT(LEG.LEG#)
---------- ---------------
        44               4
        57               4
        61               4
        62               3
        65               4
        71               5
        73               3
        75               5
        80               5
        90               4
        93               5

        T# COUNT(LEG.LEG#)
---------- ---------------
        97               5
        98               4
       101               4
       107               3


SQL> desc trktripleg
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 T#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 LEG#                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
 DEPARTURE                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 DESTINATION                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)

SQL> desc trktrip
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 T#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 L#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 REG#                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 TRKTRIP_DATE                              NOT NULL DATE
```

Comment: which is true? `MySQL` or `Oracle`?

Comment: oracle i am using sorry.

Comment: can you explain what are those results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(c)
FROM (SELECT leg.T#,COUNT(leg.LEG#) c
FROM trktripleg leg,trktrip trip 
WHERE leg.T#  = trip.T# AND trip.L#='10001' 
GROUP BY leg.T#);
```